# lighttpd mod_auth using LDAP

Tags: ldap, authentication, lighttpd

I've setup lighttpd to use an ldap backend like so:

```
auth.debug = 2
auth.backend = "htdigest"
auth.backend.ldap.hostname = "ldap.xxxxx.com"
auth.backend.ldap.base-dn = "ou=active,ou=employees,ou=people,o=xxxxx.com"
auth.backend.ldap.allow-empty-pw = "disable"

auth.require = ("/report" =>
        (
        "method" => "basic",
        "realm" => "restricted",
        "require" => "valid-user"
        )
    )
```

When I visit the URL, I am prompted for my credentials. I enter them in, and I am immediately asked for them again, with a single line in the log:

```
(http_auth.c.877) get_password failed, IP: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

Like most things I post on StackExchange, I'm certain I'm doing something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 things were wrong:

1. `auth.backend = "ldap"`
2. `auth.backend.ldap.filter = "(uid=$)"`

Bob's you're uncle.